# How can I find out if the background from a bounding-box is inside the cropping area?

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, geometry, bounding-box

I have an image which I can freely move, rotate and resize behind a fixed frame (fixed position and size). How can I find out with JavaScript/jQuery if the background from the bounding-box of the rotated image is inside the frame?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question! But: you actually want to check if the cropping area is within the bounding-box of the background. For me this is a huge difference. Feel free to edit your question. Tip: you can also inline images in your question (I'd suggest you to make it a bit smaller 300px - 500px width).

Comment: Have you tried searching? The [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) was new to me. The first test worked fine with latest Firefox, but maybe there are issues with other browsers. If this is not sufficient, math, to be more precisely [trigonometics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) is what you need.

Comment: Cant you just test if every corner of the frame is in the background? With trigonometric indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Your background consists on 4 vertices. If you know them you can simply check if they're inside the frame.

If you don't have vertices but dimensions, position and rotation you can discover them using math and trigonometry.

[This answere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12161405/2001870) may help.