# Libgx Rotate a Texture Region

Tags: android, libgdx

I wonder know how to Rotate a textureRegion in Libgdx.

If there is a isue with Pixmap, you can also give it to me.

I don't want to use sprites because it's not appropiate for the thing I want do.

Thanks you.

Comment: TextureRegions do not rotate.  What do you really want to do?  Do you want to render a rotated texture to the screen?  Or combine rotated textures together?  Do you want to rotate finely (like 3 degrees) or coarsely (only 90 degrees)?

Comment: I want to rotate 90 degrees or 180 or 270. Because for some reason,If I assign a textureRegion to a Sprite, I want that the spriteRotation must be equal to 0 while the Sprite's Image is rotated to 90 for exemple.

Comment: And I don't want a fake result like : sprite.getRotation() - 90. I want that the real value sprite's angle is equal to 0

Comment: Sounds like you're (ab)using the Sprite's rotation value for some other purpose.  Might be simpler to use the Sprite rotation for the visual display like its intended, and to use a separate field to track the rotation you care about.

Comment: I don't want this way for some reason.. I really want to do it without sprite's function.. even if the issu isn't fast enought..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple to rotate a textureRegion with multiples of 90°.

A textureRegion is a portion of a bigger Texture, defined with two couples of UV coordinates.
In order to rotate your textureRegion, you juste have to rotates these UV coordinates.

For instance, here is you original textureRegion:[image: Original region]

(we're assuming that your region is a square, but it would work with a rectangle as well)
To rotate 90 clockwise, you need just have to swap coordinates:

```
u1 = u1
v1 = v2
u2 = u2
v2 = v1
```

Which will lead to:

[image: Rotated region]

You can generalize this solution with transformation matrix (rotation, translation, scaling), but for 90° multiple rotation, you just need to swap coordinates.

EDIT: [This page](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html) contains all you need you know to change UV coordinates of a textureRegion

Comment: Doesn't that only flip the texture region? (e.g. mirror it?)

Comment: I tried and it seems that this is flipping / mirroring the texture and not rotating it. Any hints ?

Comment: That page used to contain `TextureRegion`'s [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html), and I doubt this: `public TextureRegion(Texture texture, float u, float v, float u2, float v2)` is all we need to know to change UV coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

for rotating at an angle say theta (symbol @) at origin

let (x,y) be old values and

(xn,yn) be new values then

clockwise

xn=x*cos(@)+ y*sin(@)

yn=y*sin(@)-x*cos(@)

counter clockwise

xn=x*cos(@)+ y*sin(@)

yn=y*sin(@)-x*cos(@)

for along a point refer to this the diagram helps
[How to rotate a vertex around a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161277/how-to-rotate-a-vertex-around-a-certain-point)

for example a rectangle just calculate the 2 vertex position(x1,y1) and (x2,y2)

then draw as follows
width=x2-x1;
height=y2-y1;

g.drawRectangle(x,y,width,heigh);

been a while since I revised my C.G. notes but i guess above will do the trick

if using libgdx here is simple solution:
Spritebatch.draw(region, 0, 0, 128, 128, 256, 256, 1, 1, 90);
last parameter is rotation angle