# Libgdx: Rotate a TextureRegion before splitting

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to create an animation from a **textureRegion**. The regions are stored in an atlas file that is created by the LibGdx Texture Packer. The region I am interested at the moment is this:

```
mygame/myregion
rotate: true
xy: 2, 544
size: 2574, 279
orig: 2574, 279
offset: 0, 0
index: -1
```

[image: rotated image]

Note the **rotate true** property. I am following the example from the documentation here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation

The region is composed by 4 frames [it is a single png image that is composed by 4 frames not individual images] which are split later using the split method:

```
int framesCount = 4;
myRegion = skin.getRegion("mygame/myregion"),
int frameWidth = (int) Math.floor(myRegion.getRegionWidth() / (float) framesCount);
int frameHeight = myRegion.getRegionHeight();
TextureRegion[][] tmp = myRegion.split(frameWidth, frameHeight);    
System.arraycopy(tmp[0], 0, animationFrames, 0, framesCount);
```

The split work well when the texture region is NOT rotated but in this case it never worked properly. In this case the regionHeight > regionWidth.

I can find if the texture is rotated or not by checking its height / width or the AtlasRegion rotate property.

Is there a way that I can rotate the region before it is split, so before splitting it would be something like here below:

[image]

Or maybe there is a better way to obtain the regions from the skin, so when in case the region is rotated by the TexturePacker, all would still be working as expected ?

Found also this related question : [Libgx Rotate a Texture Region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023134/libgx-rotate-a-texture-region) but did not help.

As workaround I disabled the rotation when generating the pack, to avoid the problem.

Comment: If you save your four images as separate files with the same name and underscore-number suffixes (like myAnim_0.png, myAnim_1.png, myAnim_2.png, ...), then TexturePacker does this stuff for you. In your game you can load them from the atlas like this: `textureAtlas.findRegions("myAnim");`.