# java- creating a simple sprite polygon with rotation

Tags: java, libgdx, polygon, intersection

I'm trying to make a simple game in libGDX.
The main sprite is a submarine, that can rotate by its center origin (width/2,height/2).

This sprite is the only one that will spin in my game and also the only one that will need a polygon, for the rest of the sprites a rectangle bounding box is enough.
I need to create a polygon, so I can handle intersections.
The polygon would be a very simple one, with only 8 vertices.

How can I get the vertices of the polygon, if I know the position of the sprite, rotation, and origin?

This image can explain exactly what I want:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rotate a vertex around a certain point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161277/how-to-rotate-a-vertex-around-a-certain-point)

Comment: Why? I don't have any polygon yet, i want to create it first.

Comment: I assumed you had a polygon defined by vertices, and you needed help with the math for rotating them.

Comment: I actualy need both..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Polygon](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html) for that and define the body manually. It might look like the following, starting at the bottom left vertex and going clock-wise until bottom right. You can of course change those values and adjust it to your sprite.

```
float[] vertices = new float[] {
    -2,   -2,
    -2,    2,
    -0.5f, 2,
    -0.5f, 3,
     0.5f, 3,
     0.5f, 2,
     2,    2,
     2,   -2
};

Polygon submarine = new Polygon();
submarine.setVertices(vertices);
```

Now you can rotate this polygon, just like the sprite, and move it and scale it. Just make sure you keep the polygon and your sprite synchronized. For collisions you can use [Intersector](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html).

For debugging of the polygon you can use a [ShapeRenderer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) to render it on your screen.

```
shapeRenderer.begin();
shapeRenderer.polygon(polygon.getTransformedVertices());
shapeRenderer.end();
```

Comment: How can I draw to a spritebatch a polygon? i want to define 8 points, and move each one with the keyboard, until i have the perfect match.

Comment: @Paul I edited my answer. You can use the shaperenderer for the polygon or single points.

Comment: Is there a way to draw the polygon on the spritebatch? Because mine got a camera attached, that is always moving, folowing my submarine, and the polygon goes in front always

Comment: You can also attach it to the shaperenderer.getProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)

Comment: Thanks, and i also got a problem. My polygon is - 126.0f, 194.0f, 115.0f, 210.0f, 143.0f,
   227.0f, 148.0f, 240.0f, 168.0f, 247.0f, 177.0f, 228.0f, 196.0f,
   227.0f, 188.0f, 191.0f . If i set the origin point to submarine picture origin, the rotation is not from its center.. what i need to do?

Comment: Your vertices seem weird to me. It looks like you captured those points when your sprite was not at (0, 0), but somewhere at ~ (125, 220). Capture the polygon's vertices around the real origin (0, 0).