# Best way to track a point on canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I've a canvas with a circle at x|y (eg. x:100, y:90) like this:

[image: Canvas with circle]

Now I rotate the canvas with `canvas.rotate()` around center:

[image: Rotated canvas]

What is the best way to get the **absolute position of the circle after rotation**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trigonometry problem

Understand that in your original non-rotated canvas, the point is at a certain angle and a certain length from center... Polar coordinates. Then when the canvas is rotated, it is still at that same location, relative to the canvas, so it's absolute position has the same length from center, with angle = original angle plus the rotation on the container canvas.

Do you remember your trigonometry? ;)

Comment: Yes, but what is the best way to get the new coordinates? Calculating the angle? Or is there a better way to do so with the Android SDK?

Comment: I think so. The other way I've done it is using affine transforms, but that doesn't seem to be available in android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161277/how-to-rotate-a-vertex-around-a-certain-point

Comment: I've done it with a Matrix: https://gist.github.com/timoschwarzer/49406ee907ffc3fce9af