# How to translate points and their container 90 degrees

Tags: java, rotation, geometry, point

I have a number of points represented by x and y. They are contained within a rectangle. I need to be able to rotate the points and their container 90 degrees. The effect would be like turning a page from portrait to landscape. So it isn't enough just to rotate the points around an origin. They also need to be translated (I think) to reflect their container also being rotated.

1. If you think of a point near the top of a piece of A4 paper.
2. Rotate the point 90 degrees. The point is now off the paper - to the right hand side of it. The x and y co-ordinates relate to the paper being in portrait orientation.
3. Change the paper so it is also rotated 90 degrees.

The problem with the x and y of the point is that they are relative to 0,0 of the portrait page not the landscape one. So they need translating in some way so they are relative to 0,0 of the landscape paper.

Comment: The rotation part is straightforward (enough), but can you speak a bit about the translation?

Comment: This isn't clear - are you just talking about a rotation around a point other than the origin?

Comment: From what I understand youre trying to rotate the rectangle along with the points in it around one of the corners of the rectangle? If thats what youre trying to do, you might want to check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161277/how-to-rotate-a-vertex-around-a-certain-point

Comment: I've tried to make it clearer