# Rotate a point around another point, when the user move his/her mouse?

Tags: java

I've spent almost a week to figure this out, but I still cant find a solution.
The language is Java.
Bellow is my current formula for rotating a random point:

```
rotatedx = (int) ((x - centerx)*Math.cos(theta) - (y - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + centerx);
rotatedy = (int) ((y - centery)*Math.cos(theta) + (y - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + centery);
```

Bellow is how I calculate theta (trying to make the point rotate when the user moves his/her mouse):

```
double dx = mousex - centerx;
double dy = mousey - centery;
theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
```

The formula works, sort of.

```
int onex = 100, oney = 100;
int twox = 150, twoy = 100;
int threex = 100, threey = 150;
int fourx = 150, foury = 150;
int centerx = 125, centery = 125;

onex = (int) ((onex - centerx)*Math.cos(theta) - (oney - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + centerx);
oney = (int) ((oney - centery)*Math.cos(theta) + (oney - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + centery);
    
twox = (int) ((twox - centerx)*Math.cos(theta) - (twoy - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + centerx);
twoy = (int) ((twoy - centery)*Math.cos(theta) + (twoy - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + centery);
    
threex = (int) ((threex - centerx)*Math.cos(theta) - (threey - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + centerx);
threey = (int) ((threey - centery)*Math.cos(theta) + (threey - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + centery);
    
fourx = (int) ((fourx - centerx)*Math.cos(theta) - (foury - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + centerx);
foury = (int) ((foury - centery)*Math.cos(theta) + (foury - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + centery);
```

But it only works when all point's (including the center point) X equals to it's Y, so only point one and four works. Point two and three were in a weird motion, moving back and forth passing through the center point.

Perhaps Someone could tell me how to rotate a point around another point when the user move's the mouse? or how do I convert the Theta value into degrees and rotate the point with degrees instead of theta?

Its my first time posting on this site.

Comment: Assuming you have taken those calculations e.g. from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161277/how-to-rotate-a-vertex-around-a-certain-point you should for now try to keep the format / order of the calculations the same. all `y` calculations for example only have `y` parts, no `x` parts at all, that is wrong already. `x = cx + dx cos - dy sin` and `y = cy + dx sin + dy cos`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in rotating formula for rotatedy, you use `(y - centery)` in both expressions. There should be `x` in the second term:

```
rotatedy = (int) ((y - centery)*Math.cos(theta) + (x - centerx)*Math.sin(theta) + centery);
```

The same is true for `oney`, `twoy`, `threey`, `foury`.

Comment: I've tried this, but the second term actually does take two Y.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, I was being stupid.

Instead of Transforming the original point's X and Y,

```
onex = (int) ((onex - centerx)*Math.cos(theta) - (oney - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + 
centerx);
oney = (int) ((oney - centery)*Math.cos(theta) + (oney - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + 
centery);
```

I should declare a new point, and my formula was incorrect:

```
newonex = (int) ((onex - centerx)*Math.cos(theta) - (oney - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + 
centerx);
newoney = (int) ((onex - centerx)*Math.cos(theta) + (oney - centery)*Math.sin(theta) + 
centery);
```